# How can I in Bitrix with an API request update the "ACTIVE" field of a list?

Tags: bitrix

I have a custom list in **Bitrix** CRM and want to activate/deactivate certain elements of it. For the elements I have of course the element_id and the **IBLOCK**_ID of the list.
But I dont manage to update the **ACTIVE field** of an element. Is this possible with a REST **API call**.
I tried it with the devops console in my Bitrix and the request sends a positive answer, but doesnt update the ACTIVE field.

This is how I tried it
[https://myserver.com/rest/myid/mykey/lists.element.update.json?IBLOCK_TYPE_ID=lists&IBLOCK_ID=25&ELEMENT_ID=123456&FIELDS[NAME]=something&FIELDS[PROPERTY_156]=CO_1111&FIELDS[ACTIVE]=Y](https://myserver.com/rest/myid/mykey/lists.element.update.json?IBLOCK_TYPE_ID=lists&IBLOCK_ID=25&ELEMENT_ID=123456&FIELDS%5BNAME%5D=something&FIELDS%5BPROPERTY_156%5D=CO_1111&FIELDS%5BACTIVE%5D=Y)

Comment: Your link is not working! Share here whatever you were planning to share

Comment: Sure, because I replaced confident values with obviously fake information. But the structure of my API call should be understandable.

Comment: It seems like writing a custom component will be the best approach for your, take a look at https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=14014.